# Dynamic height in cell Issue in iPhone6 and iPhone6 plus

Tags: ios, uilabel, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, custom-cell

I am implementing a functionality in which all labels of my cell has been resized as per the text containing with each label.I have implemented this functionality with the help of [RayWanderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout) and its working fine for iPhone 4s,5 and 5s with iOS 8.1. as shown in image below which shows **iPhone 5s simulator with iOS 8.1**

[image]

while I am running my app with iPhone 6 or iPhone 6 plus I got unexpected behavior as shown below image which shows **iPhone 6 simulator**

[image]

and **iPhone 6 plus simulator**.

[image]

I have created two custom cell nib files one for iPhone 4,4s,5 and 5s and second one is for iPhone 6 and 6 plus. As I am new with auto layout I have set constraints same both nibs. I am showing both custom cell nib files with set constraints at below images.

**iPhone 4,4s,5 and 5s nib file snapshot**

[image]

**iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus Custom cell nib file snapshot**

[image]

I also used following code snippet from where cell has been resized with dynamic height. The code works for iPhone iPhone 4(for iOS 7),4s,5 and 5s (for iOS 7 and iOS 8 and 8.1) fine but not for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus.

**Code Snippet**

```
- (CGFloat)calculateHeightForConfiguredSizingCell_3:(MemberListTableViewCell_WithoutImage_3_iPhone *)sizingCell {


    sizingCell.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(self.tblView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(sizingCell.bounds));

    [sizingCell setNeedsLayout];
    [sizingCell layoutIfNeeded];

    CGSize size = [sizingCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];

    //CGSize size = [sizingCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize withHorizontalFittingPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh verticalFittingPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh];

    return size.height + 1.0f; // Add 1.0f for the cell separator height
}
```

Please give me a proper solution where am I going wrong.I have surfed lot of things but unable to get proper way to solve this issue. Your help would be appreciable.Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

According to your question of cell height in iPhone6,6 Plus you need to write below lines.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0 
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Dynamic Cell Size using auto layout 
reference:  http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

Comment: it seems it's compulsory to set `estimatedRowHeight` with a value not just `UITableView.automaticDimension`  for iPhone 6 and 6 plus

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you have two different xibs for the same cell? The whole point of AutoLayout is that a single layout can be flexible enough to support all screen sizes.

When using auto sizing cells, the key things to remember are:

- `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = <estimated_value>`
- `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
- Make sure you have a non-ambiguous layout inside of your `UITableViewCell` subclass and all elements are subviews of `.contentView`

Your layout looks like a perfect fit for `UIStackView`. I would suggest using a vertical `UIStackView` containing your 3 labels. Then a horizontal `UIStackView` containing the previous `UIStackView` and the `UIImageView`. The only `NSLayoutConstraints` you would need to create would be pinning the outer `UIStackView` to all sides of `.contentView`

For more info on `UIStackViews`, check out my blog post:

http://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2016/04/uistackview/